# Selective sync in Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 in trying to implement a file sync app.
Basically I need to know what files are deleted in a directory and decide whether or not that deletion event will be applied to directories included in the sync.

For example:
Directory A is the source
Directory B is the destination

Both directories contain the same files.

If a file in Directory A is deleted, the same file must be deleted in Directory B
However if a file in directory B is deleted, it will not be synced to Directory A but will be recreated because of a sync that gets that file from Directory A. (Basically, undoing the delete that has happened in Directory B)

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try subscribing to the ApplyingChange event, skip the delete change and recreate the file from there.

Comment: is it possible to recreate the file? Is it ok if you provide a sample code that does this?

Comment: you will have to do it programmatically. it wont recreate it for you.